# why is my nav bar off screen to the left? (extreme biginner)

Tags: html, css

just like the title says, why is it doing this?: [why is adding images weird here: [pic of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHegT.png)

here is the code for it(i got it off of this [w3 schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp))

```css
/* The navigation bar */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
}


/* Links inside the navbar */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change background on mouse-over */

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
} 

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

i tried looking but no one i could find had the same issue so i came here ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You might want to read about "default css in browsers", then about "css reset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your text is distanced as well, i presume the `body` itself has a margin.

You can try to add `left: 0;` to `.navbar`:

```
.navbar { left: 0; /*...*/ }
```

Or try to remove the body margin:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```